# React-Native Integrating with Existing Apps 'RCTRootView.h' file not found

Tags: ios, react-native

I want to use React-Native [to integrate with Existing Apps]. However I get the following error:

```
'RCTRootView.h' file not found
```

As shown in the following capture:
[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/euz2i.png

Comment: I want to see you whole file tree. At this point I don't see the file `RCTRootView.h` so that is what is causing the error.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BEo8d.png      thank you

Answer (score 4):

If you are using cocoapod,

Use 

`import "React/RCTRootView.h"`

Answer (score 1):

please check the solution here:
[React native base headers for ios not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158178/react-native-base-headers-for-ios-not-found/42700452#42700452)

So the solution is to add a same configuration in React.xcodeproj to match the one in your project.

For example, if you have "Debug/Release/Test/AppStore" 4 configurations in your own project, you have to make sure React.xcodeproj has the same 4 configurations.

please Click the "+" button of Configurations, then "Duplicate Release Configuration", and rename it according to you need.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If others can not solve this issue, please try this:

`Build Settings -> Header Search Path` open it and your RN path may be like this:

```
$ (SRCROOT) / react-native / React
```

If your `node_modules` path is under the project root directory you have to modify

```
$ (SRCROOT) / node_modules / react-native / React
```

Good luck

Answer (score -4):

1. Quit XCode.
2. Open Terminal.
3. Run "npm install".