# React native base headers for ios not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, react-native, linker

During the iOS linking phase, I started seeing errors for my React Native project.

React Native version: `0.41.2`, `0.40`, `0.39`

All worked fine, I edited the Android version, React Native code didn't change, when this kind of linking errors started showing up with headers on `/node_modules/react-native/React/Base/{RCTHeaderName.h}` path not being found:

[image: The error]

```
In file included from /Users/user/ReactNativeProject/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.h:9:
../react-native/React/Base/RCTBridgeModule.h:12:9: fatal error: 'React/RCTDefines.h' file not found
#import <React/RCTDefines.h>
        ^
```

- In the **Link Binary With Libraries** I include the core React library
  (`libReact.a`).
- The location of the `RCTLog.h` is
  `PROJECTROOT/node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTLog.h`, but the
  import is `#import <React/RCTLog.h>`
- Newly adding `React.xcodeproj` into Libraries doesn't help, Xcode's `Product > Clean` doesn't help, neither does restarting Xcode
- `react-native run-android` works, `react-native run-ios` shows the error
- File permissions set to the user executing `react-native run-ios`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Do you have `Parallelize build` option unchecked and React listed first in your build targets?

[image]

You can find this window in Xcode => Your project icon near the run button => Edit scheme => Build tab

Comment: Looks like it finds the headers, after re-installing `react-native@0.41.2` and removing the excessive **Header Search Paths**. It started showing duplicate interface definition, which is a good sign..

Comment: @PeterGerhat Does deleting derived data directory help? You can find the folder in Xcode preferences => Locations tab

Comment: Probably Xcode did it already. **duplicate interface definition** was result of this change https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11725 and I just followed the steps there to fix it.

Comment: I ran into this problem while working on a native module library. In addition to disabling the parallel build, I had to add React as a Target Dependency (under Build Phases), as explained here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11721#issuecomment-270672904

Comment: This q&a should be in top list of react-native.

Comment: To find this window, click on dropdown -> Edit Scheme and highlight the Build options. In my case, however, I don't see the React output, only "luno" and "lunoTests".

Comment: @PetrusTheron There is a plus icon at bottom in the build options. Try to add React from there.

Comment: @binchik You saved my day after about 2 and a half hours of trying to figure out what happened to my project.

Comment: Sadly, I have all the settings as described and I still get the 'React/RCTLog.h' file not found.

Answer (score 5):

Update:
solution on Facebook React-Native
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11813

============

This issue happened to me also. 
It seems React.xcodeproj only recognise configuration **Debug** and **Release**. All of output of React.xcodeproj is written into **Debug-iphonesimulator** or **Release-iphonesimulator**.

That means if you have some configurations other than "Debug/Release", the output will still be written into **Debug-iphonesimulator** or **Release-iphonesimulator**, that is not what we want.

So the solution is to add a same configuration in React.xcodeproj to match the one of your own project.

For example, if you have "Debug/Release/Test/AppStore" 4 configurations in your own project, you have to make sure React.xcodeproj also has the same 4 configurations.

please click the "+" button of Configurations, then "Duplicate Release Configuration", and rename it according to you need.

[image]

Comment: Where does the name `Debug/iphonesimulator` come from? How do I know this is the config name I need?

Comment: @PetrusTheron, the correct solution is here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11813, provided by philipshurpik commented on 21 Feb

Comment: but this solution gets overwritten once you clean node_modules and reinstall them again

Comment: Not sure this problem has been fixed or not. But please use this solution:  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11813. It won't be overwritten.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like there are a lot of reasons to be getting these 'missing headers' errors and I've tried a lot of things posted on Stack Overflow and nothing would work.  Finally I stumbled upon the solution below that did work for me.  Posting in case anyone else has the same issue ... its a bit obscure.  For me it was caused by a build locations setting in Xcode that is apparently incompatible with vanilla React Native. The build locations setting that fixed this issue is shown here:

[in XCode->Settings>Locations->Advanced...  make sure your Build Location is not set to Legacy, it should be set to Unique](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMSWv.png)

Note: the vanilla React Native application may have to be reinitialized from scratch with react-native init ... after changing this setting.

Answer (score 0):

Add `path/project folder/ios/Pods/Headers/Public` in your Library's Build `Settings` -> `Header Search Path`. The issue will get resolved